# Multi-dimensional data processing alternatives

Tags: multidimensional-array, database-design, olap-cube, cubes

I am looking for a multi-dimensional data processing but without having to use any OLAP.
For example, I have a table of sales transactions. I would like to have the total sales on many dimensions like Product, State, Region, Time (monthly, quarterly) etc. The dimensions on which I need the measure (Total Sales) is dynamic and is known only at run time.

I can accomplish this using OLAP technologies (cubes). But I am looking for simpler alternatives (Open source) like possibility of using key-value databases or some software on top of RDBMS (not an ideal option considering performance needs).

Over to you folks !

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: you want the feature set of OLAP cubes without actually using OLAP cubes, and you're willing to install software to query your OLTP database in order to get those features?

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: MySQL. But I am supposed to keep it DB agnostic. But to start with, even DB specific solutions are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try build your internal queries around the "With ROLLUP" option.  Several Databases (including MySQL have this option).   This will allow you to perform OLAP cube like querying within your database by setting a few flags.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: looks promising. Will try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

[Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/) is the only open source player I know of in this arena. I'm sure there are others. I don't know whether Pentaho supports MySQL, though.

[Greenplum Community Edition](http://www.greenplum.com/products/community-edition/) is built on PostgreSQL.

Comment: Pentaho comes with its own OLAP right ? ( Mondrian). I am looking for a non-OLAP solution.